# Invariant metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have a metric that looks like the Lobachevsky upper-half space
$$ds^2 = \frac{L^2}{z_0^2}((dz_0)^2 + \sum^d_{i=1}(dz_i)^2).$$

I now want to show that this metric is invariant under the following coordinate transformation
$$z'_\mu = \frac{z_\mu}{z^2},$$ where $z^2 = \delta^{\alpha\beta}z_\alpha z_\beta$.

To do this I started computing the usual way in how the metric transforms
$$g^{{\mu'}{\nu'}} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^\rho}\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^\sigma} g^{\rho\sigma}.$$

However, I am getting stuck with $1/z^6$ and $1/z^8$ terms popping up. I guess the unconventional index placement is throwing me off a little bit

Comment: Try substituting $z_\mu =z^2  {z_\mu}^\prime$ into the metric.

Comment: Then you're mixing up coordinate systems no? Because $z^2$ is defined in terms of the unprimed coordinates

Comment: Well, then, it is the case that ${z^\prime}^2=\delta^{\alpha\beta}{z^\prime}^\alpha {z^\prime}^\beta$; and $dz_\mu={z^\prime}^2d{z^\prime}_\mu$. However, this still gives an overall factor of ${z^\prime}^2$ to the metric.

Comment: $z^{\prime {2}}= \frac{1}{z^2}$, so I think you're mixing up some stuff

Comment: How do you get that result, it doesn't follow from your post, where you define $z^2=\delta^{\alpha\beta}z^\alpha z^\beta$.

Comment: $z^{\prime {2}} = \delta^{\alpha \beta} z_\alpha^{\prime} z_\beta^{\prime} = \delta^{\alpha \beta} \frac{z_\alpha}{z^2} \frac{z_\beta}{z^2} = \frac{z^2}{z^4} = \frac{1}{z^2}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150607/discussion-between-albertus-magnus-and-geigercounter).

Comment: Chat is incredibly inefficient in my opinion. Let's keep the discussion here.

Comment: Got it, thought mabey we were required to do that or something. Don't think my suggestion was helpful at any rate. I will follow this and see if any one else can weigh in. Good luck!

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus You were right -  comments are not for extended discussions, which should take place in chats. The native chat can be supplemented by ChatJax to render mathematics (if you Google “StackExchange ChatJax” you’ll find instructions).

Answer (score 1):

$z'^\mu = \frac{z^\mu}{z^2} \implies z^\mu = \frac{z'^\mu}{z'^2}$. Using this, we have
$$
d z^\mu = \frac{d z'^\nu}{z'^2} {\cal I}^\mu_\nu(z') , \qquad {\cal I}^\mu_\nu =  \delta^\mu_\nu - 2 \frac{z'^\mu z'_\nu }{ z'^2 }  . 
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{1}{z_0^2} d z^\mu dz_\mu = \underbrace{\frac{z'^4}{z_0'^2}  }_{\frac{1}{z_0^2}} \underbrace{\frac{1}{z'^2} {\cal I}^\mu_\nu(z') d z'^\nu }_{dz^\mu} \underbrace{\frac{1}{z'^2}  {\cal I}_\mu^\alpha(z') d z'_\alpha }_{dz_\mu} = \frac{1}{z_0'^2} [ {\cal I}^2(z') ]_\nu^\alpha d z'^\nu dz'_\alpha = \frac{1}{z_0'^2} dz'^\nu dz'_\nu
$$
in the last line, we used ${\cal I}^2 = 1$ (as a matrix).

Comment: Look at the metric again! It's not $dz^2/z^2$ but $dz^2/z_0^2.$

Comment: @md2perpe - you're right. my bad - fixed.

Comment: This is quite confusing. Why are you working with indices up in some places but indices down in others?

Comment: @Geigercounter - because we can raise and lower indices? You should not be working on stuff like this if you are uncomfortable with this.

Comment: Yes but the whole point of this was that this notation is confusing to me. I don't see how a one form like $dz_\mu$ can have an index down.

Comment: $dz_\mu = \delta_{\mu\nu} dz^\nu$. BTW, this was your notation. You use the notation $z_\mu$ to describe coordinates so I assumed you know how to raise and lower indices.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding indices, setting $z=(z_0, \ldots, z_d)$ and $z^2=z_0^2+\cdots+z_d^2$ we can write
$$
z' = \frac{z}{z^2}.
$$

As Prahar points out we then also have
$$
z = \frac{z'}{{z'}^2}.
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{align}
dz &= \frac{({z'}^2) \, dz' - (2z'\cdot dz') \, {z'}}{({z'}^2)^2} \\
dz^2 &= \frac{({z'}^2)^2 d{z'}^2 - 4 ({z'}^2)(z'\cdot dz')^2 + 4 ({z'}^2)(z'\cdot dz')^2}{({z'}^2)^4}
= \frac{d{z'}^2}{({z'}^2)^2}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
z_0^2 = \frac{{z'}_0^2}{({z'}^2)^2},
$$
so,
$$
ds^2 
= \frac{dz^2}{z_0^2}
= \frac{d{z'}^2/({z'}^2)^2}{{z'}_0^2/({z'}^2)^2}
= \frac{d{z'}^2}{{z'}_0^2}
$$